# Using Rebus infront of a third-party web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rebus

I have a requirement to implement reliability, logging, etc when communicating with a third-party web service service.

Let it be known that I have completely zero control over the third-party web service in question.

I have decided to use some form of .NET Service Bus, choosing Rebus as my go to option at this point. The caller will be a web application (specifically Microsoft Dynamics 365 in the cloud), and the web service is a third-party custom Microsoft Dynamics NAV code unit).

I was wondering if anyone had any pointers at all for me in order to place Rebus between the caller and the third-party web service and how to configure it to support reliability, logging all of those nice things :)

I can currently call the third-party web service using a WCF client.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I can recommend reading the [Web Service Integration page](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Web-service-integration) on [the wiki](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/).

If you are interested in seeing some running code, there's an [Integration sample project](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples/tree/master/Integration) in the [RebusSamples repository](https://github.com/rebus-org/RebusSamples)

Comment: Thanks! I am thinking of using owin or similar to create a web server that will expose the facade web service, which will send a message to the service bus, where the service bus message handler will then make the WCF corresponding service call. Will this work? How will Rebus handle for example an exception occurring? Will it retry? How does Rebus know the WCF call succeeded? Forgive me, I'm new to Rebus :)

Comment: Additionally should the facade web server run in or out of process of the Rebus bus? I assume either will work. I would prefer to separate them.